# How to stay on the same component after refreshing a page with query string

Tags: javascript, angular, query-string

I have a component I can reach in 2 ways.

1. without query string parameters
2. with query string parameters

When I refresh the page navigated to without the query string params I get to stay on the page.
However when I refresh the page navigated to with the query string params I am redirected to the landing page.

```
  const routeMapping = [
    { path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
    {
      routerLink: 'ssccs',
      component: SsccsComponent
    },
    ...
```

when I try to add the following:

```
   {
      routerLink: 'ssccs?type=fromOverview',
      component: SsccsComponent
   },
```

it doesn't work and I return to the landing page.

What to do?

Comment: Do you have somewhere in the code CanActivate?

Comment: What do you mean by "landing page" ?

Comment: I think, you need to enable useHash:true in your app.module